# ESPN API - How can I retrieve college basketball conferences using the Teams API?

Tags: api, rest, espn

The support forums on ESPN.com recommend using Stack Overflow with the ESPN tag.  That's why I'm here.

I'm trying to obtain a list of all NCAA college basketball teams using ESPN's Teams API.  I started with this GET request:

`http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball/teams?apikey=MY_API_KEY`

That gave me a list of teams, but many of them are missing.  For example, there is no Nebraska.  So then I thought that maybe I need to get a list of teams by conference.  So I read this in the documentation:

> GROUPS:  Allows for filtering by "group" or division, e.g. AL East, NFC South, etc. For group IDs and their corresponding values, make a request to http://developer.espn.com/v1/{resource}/leagues. Not applicable to golf and tennis.

So then I try to make a request to `http://developer.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball/leagues?apikey=MY_API_KEY' and it says the page does not exist.

Is this a bug or user error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you forgot `sports` in the resource. Try this:

`http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball?apikey=MY_API_KEY&leagues`

That will return a mapping of integers to conferences it seems according to the [documentation](http://developer.espn.com/docs/teams#parameters).

That fetched me:

```
{"name" :"Atlantic Coast Conference","abbreviation" :"acc","groupId" :2,"shortName" :"ACC"}
```

...and much more.

Then once you have that, let's say 2 = ACC. You should be able to do this:

`http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball?groups=2&apikey=MY_API_KEY'`

to get everything on ACC mens' basketball teams.

Bear in mind the API is in beta though.

Comment: Good catch. But it still gives me a 404 error. I will update the question with the new URL.

Comment: Try again. I made an edit. It looks like `leagues` needs to be a query param rather than a path param as you had it before.

Comment: You don't need the &leagues GET parameter here.  You can find a list of Helper API Calls at http://developer.espn.com/overview#helper-api-calls.  These describe how to get the different groups inside a league.  It does seem that the documentation needs to be edited for the /leagues endpoint you found - that endpoint was deprecated a long time ago and seems to have been missed from that page.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to get a list of conferences, but I found out how to get the missing teams.  When I was making the first get request, it was limiting me to 50 results by default:

`http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball/teams?apikey=MY_API_KEY`

They have a sandbox where you can play with your parameters, and I saw a `limit` and `offset` option:

http://developer.espn.com/io-docs

To get more than 50 results, you have to make multiple requests using the `limit` and `offset` parameters.

First Call:
`http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball/teams/?limit=50&offset=0&_accept=text%2Fxml&apikey=MY_API_KEY`

Next Call:
`http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball/teams/?limit=50&offset=50&_accept=text%2Fxml&apikey=MY_API_KEY`

And so on...